# How to solve authentication error for capistrano 3.2 on production server using rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, ubuntu-14.04

I have been following https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04#capistrano to get a rails app up and running on a production server but currently stuck @ cap production deploy.

I am getting an authentication error. see below:

```
 INFO[6a293724] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/myapp/ on actual_ip_address
 DEBUG[6a293724] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/myapp/
 cap aborted!
 SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host actual_ip_address: Authentication failed for user actual_user@actual_ip_address
 /home/actual_user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@myapp/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:219:in `start'
```

this is my production.rb

```
 role :app, %w{actual_user@actual_ip_address}
 role :web, %w{actual_user@actual_ip_address}
 #role :db,  %w{actual_user@actual_ip_address}


 # Extended Server Syntax
 # ======================
 # This can be used to drop a more detailed server definition into the
 # server list. The second argument is a, or duck-types, Hash and is
 # used to set extended properties on the server.

 server 'actual_ip_address', user: 'actual_user', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: :my_value

 # Custom SSH Options
 # ==================
 # You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
 # limited set of options, consult[net/ssh documentation](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start).
 #
 # Global options
 # --------------
   set :ssh_options, {
     keys: %w('/home/actual_user/.ssh/id_rsa'),
     forward_agent: true,
     auth_methods: %w(publickey)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll have to include your password (annoyingly) the capistrano configuration:

```
#config/deploy/production.rb
server '***.***.***.***', roles: %w{web app}, user: "root", password: "your_pass"
```

The problem, I believe, is your SSH client won't have the capacity to demand a password input from Capistrano, hence causing the authentication issue. We had the same issue

I would test by including the password, as above